# Condição if - else if sendo ignorada pelo navegador

Tags: javascript, angularjs, if, file-upload, condição

Galera eu tenho a seguinte condição if - else if para verificação de upload de arquivo, dependendo do arquivo ele aloca em uma posição do array, entretanto ao chegar o nome para fazer a validação ele ignora os ifs e else if entrando em todos os laços sobrescrevendo tudo onde não deveria.

To usando AngularJs, já debuguei e inclusive tentei trocar o if para switch, mas ele continua ignorando e entrando em todos os laços sobrescrevendo tudo. Alguem sabe me informar o motivo, causa ou circustância dessa bruxaria? Eu sei que o método não é o melhor e inclusive irei modificar mas queria entender por que ele entra em todos.

Se a receita for "receita-torta" ele deveria entrar somente no segundo laço e ignorar o primeiro e terceiro, porém ele entra em todos sobrescrevendo as informações deles.

```
$scope.setContentToDocument = function(value, name) {

    if ($scope.data.documents != undefined) {
        if ($scope.data.documents.length <= 3) {
            let object = {
                documentNumberOrName: name,
                fieldNumOrName: false,
                fieldNumOrNameDI: false,
                fieldNumOrNameEstimativa: false,
                fileUploadRequired: false,
                requiredDoc: false,
                type: "RECEITAS",
            }

            let file = {};

            if (name == "receita-bolo") {
                file = {
                    content: value.contentAsString,
                    name: value.fileName,
                };

                if ($scope.data.documents[0] != undefined) {
                    $scope.data.documents[0].file.name = value.fileName;
                    $scope.data.documents[0].file.content = value.contentAsString;
                } else {
                    object.file = file;
                    $scope.data.documents.push(object);
                }

            } else if (name == "receita-torta") {
                file = {
                    content: value.contentAsString,
                    name: value.fileName,
                };

                if ($scope.data.documents[1] != undefined) {
                    $scope.data.documents[1].file.name = value.fileName;
                    $scope.data.documents[1].file.content = value.contentAsString;
                } else {
                    object.file = file;
                    $scope.data.documents.push(object);
                }
            } else if (name == "receita-pizza") {
                file = {
                    content: value.contentAsString,
                    name: value.fileName,
                };

                if ($scope.data.documents[2] != undefined) {
                    $scope.data.documents[2].file.name = value.fileName;
                    $scope.data.documents[2].file.content = value.contentAsString;
                } else {
                    object.file = file;
                    $scope.data.documents.push(object);
                }
            }
            console.log($scope.data.documents)
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: *" entrando em todos os laços "* que laços? não vejo nenhum nesse código. Você só cria a variável "object" se essa condição for verdade `if ($scope.data.documents.length <= 3)`, e se ela não for e entrar nos ifs abaixo vai dar erro de *undefined* na variável "object". Os ifs estão corretos, não vejos como pode entrar em todos. Além disso, a variável "file" é sempre igual, podia declarar uma única vez no lugar de fazer `let file = {};`

Comment: É verdade, não há laços com o sono que eu estava acabei usando termo errado hahaha. Então, apesar de eu também não ver como entrar em todos, as variáveis dentro de cada if acabam sendo mudadas e todo o array $scope.data.documents[] é preenchido

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O `if / else if` com certeza não vai entrar em todos, pois as condições são diferentes, e a variável `name` não é alterada no processo, mas seu código pode ser melhorado para ficar mais simples, claro, e menor. Abaixo uma sugestão:

```
$scope.setContentToDocument = function(value, name) {

    if ($scope.data.documents != undefined) {
           
      let object = {
        documentNumberOrName: name,
        fieldNumOrName: false,
        fieldNumOrNameDI: false,
        fieldNumOrNameEstimativa: false,
        fileUploadRequired: false,
        requiredDoc: false,
        type: "RECEITAS",
        file: {
          content: value.contentAsString,
          name: value.fileName,
        }
      };

      if (name == "receita-bolo") {
        $scope.data.documents[0] = object;
      } else if (name == "receita-torta") {
        $scope.data.documents[1] = object;
      } else if (name == "receita-pizza") {
        $scope.data.documents[2] = object;
      }

      console.log($scope.data.documents)
    }
};
```

Fazendo `$scope.data.documents.push(object)` está adicionando no "próximo" elemento livre, e não garante que por exemplo que se vier "receita-bolo", será adicionado ao elemento "0".

Já fazendo assim `$scope.data.documents[0] = object` garante o índice correto, isso partindo do princípio que vai setar sempre os 3, senão precisa de uma mais uma lógica antes de setar o elemento

Comment: Rapaz, você salvou minha vida. Do jeito que estava antes, de alguma forma ele substituia todos os anexos existentes ao realizar upload, da Receita de Pizza. O $scope.data.documents.push(object) que deveria estar bagunçando tudo, pois além de adicionar um indice vazio toda vez que o botão de upload era acionado, ele inseria no lugar errado.

Comment: boa, espere que de certo agora. Se a resposta te ajudou ou resolveu sua dúvida, não esqueça de votar ou aceitar a resposta :)